# WinUI 3. Programmatically scroll listview using MVVM

Tags: listview, mvvm, scroll, winui-3

I'm trying to programmatically scroll the content of a listview, using two buttons, (one for each direction) and the MvvM pattern.

So far all other solutions i could find made use of `x:Name` and the code behind to access the listview and call `ScrollIntoView(Object)` function. I thought i could make use of the [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=winrt-22621) and the `FindChildren<T>`, however this also requires the `x:Name` to find and return the listview object for my ViewModel to use.

Xaml:

```
<!-- ListView to scroll through: -->
<ListView
    SelectionMode="None"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfListItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="UcViewModel:ListItemViewModel">
                <Uc:ListItemUserControl/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<!-- One of my two buttons: -->
<Button
    Content="Scroll up"
    Command="{Binding ScrollUp}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private DelegateCommand _scrollUp;
public ICommand ScrollUp => _scrollUp ??= new DelegateCommand(PerformScrollUp);

private void PerformScrollUp(object commandParameter)
{
    //Here i want to call ListView.BringIntoView(NextItem)
}
```

The MVVM library I'm using is the: `Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm`

I've tried reading through documentation as well, but as far as i understand i need to find a way to access the ListView Object in my ViewModel, and I'm unable to figure out how I would achieve this. I am somewhat new both to WinUI 3 and C#, so please say if there is any missing info, and I'll do my best to provide what is needed.

Edit: As I'm using DI for all pages and ViewModels, I do believe it's impossible to simply inject the listview into the ViewModels constructor in the code behind, using the x:Name. That said I'm looking to keep the code-behind as untouched as possible, to follow the MVVM pattern.

Comment: So, what's the problem when you use define x:Name for the ListView in XAML?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no way to access the x:Name any other places than the codebehind, meaning my ViewModel wouldn't be able to make use of it. 


Ofc it's technically possible to inject the ListView into the viewmodels constructor in the code behind, using x:Name. However im using DI for all pages and ViewModels, which i believe invalidates this option for me (I'll add this info to the question)

Comment: x:Name is the same as FrameworkElement.Name (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.name) and you can walk the visual tree https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namescopes

Comment: If it's just scrolling (no other complicated business logic) and is UI related, I think that you should do it in code-behind. Otherwise, you're just going from UI to ViewModel to interact with UI.

Comment: I regards to Simon. I'll try and take a look at walking the visual tree to get my solution. Besides the visualtreehelper i don't have any experience with this. 

And yes Andrew it have definitely crossed my mind to just do it in code behind, and it is my backup solution. However i know that i'll need to return multiple times in the future to update the visual layer and its needed in multiple locations, so MVVM would be the ideal. Besides that i see it as a good opportunity to improve and learn.

Comment: Sadly i do not think I'm experienced enough to walk the visual tree, and solve my problem this way. I tried getting hold of the Frameworkelement using `(FrameworkElement)Window.Current.Content`, to enable use of the `.FindName()`, only to learn this need to be done through the UI thread, else it returns null, Trying with a Dispatcher yielded no luck either. I have learned that attached behaviors is a thing, and it's possible that it can lead me to a solution, tho it might end as a bit hack job, but it's something im looking into.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to implement something like "SelectFirstItem" instead of "ScrollUp" for the button logic in your viewmodel? If you just select items in your viewmodel then the view could react by an 'SelectionChanged" event in the code behind to always scroll to the currently selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having put my problem a bit behind me and looked at it with new eyes, i found the following solution. However I'm unaware about its efficiency, and / or if it is bad coding principle.

What I do, is passing the control to the view model via the `CommandParameter`, and binding it with x:Bind to the required controls name. This technically uses bindings to the code-behind, however the code-behind it self is left unmodified.

In the xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer
   x:Name = "TargetScrollViewer">
   <ListView>
      //Disables listviews internal scrollviewer
      //Implement rest of ListView code
   </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>

<Button
   Command = "{Binding ScrollUp}"
   CommandParameter = "{x:Bind TargetScrollViewer}"/>

<Button
   Command = "{Binding ScrollDown}"
   CommandParameter = "{x:Bind TargetScrollViewer}"/>
```

Many seems to recommend using the listviews "ScrollIntoView", If this is the case just parse the Listview rather than the scrollviewer as the command parameter.

And inside the viewmodel:

```
private DelegateCommand _scrollDown;
public ICommand ScrollDown => _scrollDown ??= new DelegateCommand(PerformScrollDown);

private void PerformScrollDown(object commandParameter)
{
    var scrollcontrol = commandParameter as ScrollViewer;
    scrollcontrol.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollcontrol.VerticalOffset + 72);
}
```

Inside the function I simply cast the command parameter back to a Scrollviewer, and call the required functions.

In my case I'm using "Syncfusion" for the DelegateCommand to bind buttons to the view.

Comment: Your ViewModel should not know any UI exists. If you put ViewModels to separate project without reference to any UI framework, your solution wouldn't even be possible. Or if you wanted to make two UIs - one WPF and one for example Avalonia.
You can create button event handler in your SomePage.xaml.cs which will directly call MyScrollViewer.Scroll(). This is all UI related stuff, not VM.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This makes a lot of sense. Luckily for me while i guess its true that i break the MVVM pattern, these cases will not be relevant in my project. But i will decently keep this in mind for future projects and code.

Answer (score 0):

In my `ViewModel`, in addition to implementing the `ItemsSource`, I also implement `SelectedItem` and property bind both to my `ListView`. In the following example, I use the MVVM pattern to implement a console-like application (whereby updates to the console would append lines to the collection and update the selected line/index):

```cs
   public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> ConsoleLines = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public string? SelectedConsoleLine = null;
        public int SelectedConsoleIndex = -1;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Then, in my XAML, I can configure my ListView:

```xml
        <ListView x:Name="ConsoleView"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource consoleTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ConsoleLines}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConsoleLine,Mode=TwoWay}">
        </ListView>
```

In the code-behind for the View, we listen to the ViewModel's PropertyChange event to implement scrolling, e.g.

```cs
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
        PrimesButton.Clicked += PrimesButton_Clicked;
        ClearButton.Clicked += ClearButton_Clicked;
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    }
    private void ViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            // ConsoleView is ListView
            case nameof(viewModel.SelectedConsoleLine):
                ConsoleView.ScrollTo(viewModel.SelectedConsoleLine, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true); // ListView
                break;
            // ConsoleView is CollectionView
            //case nameof(ViewModel.SelectedConsoleIndex):
            //    ConsoleView.ScrollTo(viewModel.SelectedConsoleIndex);
            //    break;
        }
    }
```